# Why for creating a new test coin is suggested to use Litecoin code?

Tags: altcoin, genesis-block

I think I'd prefer to use Bitcoin code. Is there a reason that LiteCoin is preferred?

As far as I know, for creating a different coin from BTC source I need to create a genesis block and remove the checkpoints. And obviously change any important parameter that I think should be changed (block rewards, etc.).

Is anything else needed? Maybe it's hard to create a genesis block for Bitcoin?

Comment: *who* said that?!?

Comment: where did you get this assumption?

Comment: I've found that suggestion in the "BitcoinTalk" forum:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0

But I've just realized is on the "altcoin discussion" forum.

Anyway, I haven't found a good tutorial on forking Bitcoin (specially the genesis block part) but this, related with LiteCoin, was easier to find.